# Drawing with Cytoscape as a general-purpose whiteboard

Tags: drawing, cytoscape.js, cytoscape-web, whiteboard

Cytoscape JS is not designed specifically as a general-purpose drawing tool, but rather for the visualization of structured data, I'm curious as to whether anyone has created a plugin or set of libraries to enable Cytoscape's use as a virtual whiteboard or drawing tool - for quickly sketching diagrams, flowcharts, or any kind of free-form drawing.